# How to get my code to stop printing a keyword in my web crawler

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-requests

New to python and just playing around with a web crawler using bs4 and requests modules. Currently the code keeps printing in instance of my keyword and was wondering how to get it to only to print once. 
    Do I use a "break" and where would i insert that into my code?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Test for agency offering scrape
def seo(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text)
    lowercased = result.text.lower()
    keywords = ['creative']
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword.lower() in lowercased:
            print (keyword)

    links = soup.find_all('a')[1:]
    for link in links:
        seo(link['href'])
seo("http://www.daileyideas.com/")
```

Comment: It's not clear what your expected behavior is. Do you want to stop iterating over `links` as soon as you find your keyword in `lowercased`?

Comment: yes, sorry new to this and my questions may not be in the context of experienced pythoners.

Comment: what do you want to do with the `for link in links:` loop if you end the function in the previous loop?

Comment: So when i enter this code in my console. It keeps printing "creative" and looks like it is continuous loop. I want to stop the loop once it only finds one instance of it. (if that makes sense.)

Comment: @user3802773, I added an answer but I think there are probably easier ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exit your function when you find the keyword just `return`:

```
def seo(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text)
    lowercased = result.text.lower()
    found=False
    keywords = ['creative']
    print keywords[0] in lowercased
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword.lower() in lowercased:
            found =True
    links = soup.find_all('a')[1:]
    for link in links:
        if not found:
            seo(link['href'])
        else:
            print(keyword)
            return
```

This function will get all the links on the first page and visit each one until the keyword is found or we run out of links:

```
import urlparse
def seo(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text)
    links = [urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href']) for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True)] # get all links on the page
    lower_cased = result.text.lower()
    keywords = ['creative']
    while links: # keep going until list is empty
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword.lower() in lower_cased:
                print "Success we found the keyword: {}".format(keyword)
                return
        link = links.pop() # get next link to check
        result = requests.get(link)
        lower_cased = result.text.lower()
```

In your recursive search you would need to set some depth limit or if the keyword is not found your search will keep going.  [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) has the tools to do what you want so if you really  want to do that it would be worth checking it out.

Comment: Awesome stuff thanks! I just added "return keyword" and it worked! Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Using break would just exit that loop and move to the next

Comment: Note that this won't work as desired if the first url visited doesn't contain the keyword. Once you enter the second for loop you'll stay in it until it's done, even if you `print keyword` multiple times.

Comment: @user3802773, I edited my code, there is another issue in your code I will fix it later I am on my phone so atm so will edit when I get back to computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should return something from `seo` that indicates a match was found. Then the calling code can check that return value, and when the return value indicates there was a match, it can break out of the loop:

```
def seo(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text)
    lowercased = result.text.lower()
    keywords = ['creative']
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword.lower() in lowercased:
            print (keyword)
            return True # Found a match

    links = soup.find_all('a')[1:]
    for link in links:
        if seo(link['href']):
            return True
    return False # No match
```

Comment: yes this also works too! Thanks! thanks for also editing my code as I am new to this.

Comment: `links = soup.find_all('a')[1:]` will never be reached.